# Skip steps on a django FormWizard

Tags: python, django, formwizard

I have an application where there is a FormWizard with 5 steps, one of them should only appear when some conditions are satisfied.

The form is for a payment wizard on a on-line cart, one of the steps should only show when there are promotions available for piking one, but when there are no promotions i want to skip that step instead of showing an empty list of promotions.

So I want to have 2 possible flows:

```
step1 - step2 - step3

step1 - step3
```

Comment: For anyone wanting a more recent/relevant answer, see [this](https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html#conditionally-view-skip-specific-steps).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The hook method [process_step()](https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html#formtools.wizard.views.WizardView.process_step) gives you exactly that opportunity.
After the form is validated you can modify the **self.form_list** variable, and delete the forms you don't need.

Needles to say if you logic is very complicated, you are better served creating separate views for each step/form, and forgoing the FormWizard altogether.

Comment: the process_step() method is meant to post-process data _after_ the form is submitted. to make certain forms optional you can introduce conditionals in the list of forms you pass to the FormView:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#conditionally-view-skip-specific-steps

Comment: The project has since been moved to it's own package and the working link to @tijs comment is here --  https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html#conditionally-view-skip-specific-steps
I would also like to note that process_step() method is a useful one to use for coding up the idea, and once you are comfortable with how the logic works, you should move the logic to condition_dict.

Answer (score 4):

To make certain forms optional you can introduce conditionals in the list of forms you pass to the FormView in your urls.py:

```
contact_forms = [ContactForm1, ContactForm2]

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^contact/$', ContactWizard.as_view(contact_forms,
        condition_dict={'1': show_message_form_condition}
    )),
)
```

For a full example see the Django docs: https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html#conditionally-view-skip-specific-steps

Answer (score 1):

I did it other way, overriding the render_template method. Here my solution. I didn't know about the process_step()...

```
def render_template(self, request, form, previous_fields, step, context):

    if not step == 0:
        # A workarround to find the type value!
        attr = 'name="0-type" value='
        attr_pos = previous_fields.find(attr) + len(attr)
        val = previous_fields[attr_pos:attr_pos+4]
        type = int(val.split('"')[1])

        if step == 2 and (not type == 1 and not type == 2 and not type == 3):
            form = self.get_form(step+1)
            return super(ProductWizard, self).render_template(request, form, previous_fields, step+1, context)

    return super(ProductWizard, self).render_template(request, form, previous_fields, step, context)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways for this(as mentioned in other answers), but one solution which I think could be useful is overwriting the `get_form_list()` method:

something like:

```
from collections import OrderedDict 
def get_form_list(self):

        form_list = OrderedDict()

        // add some condition based on the earlier forms
        cleaned_data = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('step1') or {}

        for form_key, form_class in self.form_list.items():
            if cleaned_data and cleaned_data['step1'] == 'X':
                 if form_key == 'step2':
                    #skip step2
                    continue
                 else:
                    pass
            elif cleaned_data and cleaned_data['step1'] == 'Y':
                 if form_key == 'step4':
                     #skip step4
                     continue
                 else:
                     pass

              ....
                  
            # try to fetch the value from condition list, by default, the form
            # gets passed to the new list.
            condition = self.condition_dict.get(form_key, True)
            if callable(condition):
                # call the value if needed, passes the current instance.
                condition = condition(self)
            if condition:
                form_list[form_key] = form_class
        return form_list
```

I think in this way you can handle complicated forms and you'r not gonna have any conflict with other stuffs.